# How to push keys (values) with requests module python3?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, lxml

I'm trying to push some value in the search box of amazon.com.
I'm using requests rather then selenium (push keys option). 
I've identified the xpath of the search box, and now want to push value in it, IE: char "a" or "apple" or any other string and then collect the results.
However when pushing the data with the post method for request I get an error.
Here below it's my code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)''AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/', headers=headers)


page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/', headers=headers)
response_code = page.status_code
if response_code == 200:
    htmlText = page.text
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    search_box = tree.xpath('//input[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
    pushing_keys = requests.post(search_box,'a')
    print(search_box)
```

However I get this error code:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL "[<InputElement 20b94374a98 name='field-keywords' type='text'>]": No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://[<InputElement 20b94374a98 name='field-keywords' type='text'>]?
```

How do I correctly push any char in the search box with requests?
Thanks

Comment: learn the convention (particular endpoints) of changing that searchbox first. Currently the above approach makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach:

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)''AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
response_code = page.status_code
if response_code == 200:
    key_word_to_search = 'bean bags'
    pushing_keys = requests.get(f'{base_url}/s/ref=nb_sb_noss', headers=headers, params={'k': key_word_to_search})
    print(pushing_keys.content)
```

The search box is using a get request.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiCb8.png)